Python telegram bot with pyrogram stopped receiving messages from some channels
My telegram bot built using python and pyrogram was working properly i.e. receiving all the messages from all telegram subscribed channels. It started having the following problems:

Not receiving messages from telegram channels
Not receiving all the messages received on the telegram channels

from pyrogram import Client, filters

TELEGRAM_API_ID = xxxxx
TELEGRAM_API_HASH = "xxxxx"
TELEGRAM_BOT_TOKEN = "xxxxx" 
TELEGRAM_BOT_NAME="xxxxx"
bot = Client(TELEGRAM_BOT_NAME, api_id=TELEGRAM_API_ID, api_hash=TELEGRAM_API_HASH)

bot.on_message(filters.channel)
async def telegram_bot_main(client, message):
   print(message.text)
bot.run()

I expect to :

To receive all the messages from all subscribed channels


Did you miss something @ from the decorator.
@bot.on_message(filters.channel)
async def telegram_bot_main(client, message):
   print(message.text)

Addition to the answer:
I also encountered a similar problem
when the client suddenly stopped receiving updates
from the channel I was interested in.

From participating in an exciting program, I received the following comments:
"Chats fell off on average from 1k users, groups from 100k.
Now people are looking for the cause of the error, but this is open source, as they will find it fixed.".
Pay attention to these warnings:
# Pyrogram is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
# but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
# MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
# GNU Lesser General Public License for more details.

You can "manually" receive updates, to do this, you need to use the
TELEGRAM RAW API :

Raw Functions
Raw Types
Raw Base

Or start working with TDLib
An example of TDLib in Python
Python Wrapper TDLib

Thank you but sometimes it not receiving  messages from some channels

@KudzaiMadziva , I also faced a similar problem as in this question
And I'm trying to figure out what the problem is.
You can specify the Pyrogram version and provide chat.id from which updates cannot be processed? Please update the question so that it has details that will allow me to reproduce the problem.

I solved the problem  i.e Python telegram bot with pyrogram stopped receiving messages from some channels by  switching to Telethon> Now everything is working
